# Optimizing Mysql Left Join with 800,000+ rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query I am running on a database with 800,000 records however the load time is over 20 seconds. I have indexes on all the columns, can anyone suggest a better query format to load these results in under 1. second?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS st.location_limit 
                         , u.user_id
                         , IF(listing_type = 'Company', company, last_name) name 
                      FROM users_data u
                      JOIN subscription_types st
                        ON st.subscription_id = u.subscription_id 
                     WHERE u.active = 2 
                       AND st.searchable = 1  
                     GROUP 
                        BY u.user_id 
                     ORDER 
                        BY st.search_priority ASC 
                     LIMIT 10;
```

Here is my explain

```
id  select_type  table               partitions  type  possible_keys                                    key                  key_len  ref                                                       rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       subscription_types  NULL        ALL   PRIMARY,searchable,id_searchable,search_results  NULL                 NULL     NULL                                                      4       Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       users_data          NULL        ref   subscription_id,active,subscription_active       subscription_active  8        findades_anti315.subscription_types.subscription_id,const 209261
```

Entire Query is here 
Here is the entire query. Thank you.

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS subscription_types.location_limit as location_limit,users_data.user_id,users_data.last_name,users_data.filename,users_data.user_id,users_data.phone_number,users_data.city,users_data.state_code,users_data.zip_code,users_data.country_code,users_data.quote,users_data.subscription_id,users_data.company,users_data.position,users_data.profession_id,users_data.experience,users_data.account_type,users_data.verified,users_data.nationwide,IF(listing_type = 'Company', company, last_name) as name FROM `users_data` LEFT JOIN `users_reviews` ON users_data.user_id=users_reviews.user_id AND users_reviews.review_status='2' LEFT JOIN users_locations ON users_locations.user_id=users_data.user_id LEFT JOIN subscription_types ON users_data.subscription_id=subscription_types.subscription_id LEFT JOIN `rel_services` ON rel_services.user_id=users_data.user_id WHERE users_data.active='2' AND subscription_types.searchable='1' AND ((rel_services.service_id='1383' OR rel_services.service_id='1384' OR rel_services.service_id='1385') OR subscription_types.service_limit='all') ORDER BY subscription_types.search_priority ASC

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN. Might as well write it as such. Also, if you GROUP BY user_id - how do you know which listing_type/location_limit is being returned?

Comment: I was using the GROUP BY because I use a LEFT JOIN with other databases like our reviews table, and our other locations table. Here is the full query.

Comment: Sorry - you've lost me.

Comment: It would be better to post the entire query. Remember to include table definitions, and information about existing indexes and foreign keys.